# Calculating the fraction of the area of multiple squares overlapped by a circle

Tags: geometry

This is a geometrical question based on a programming problem I have. Basically, I have a MySQL database full of latitude and longitude points, spaced out to be 1km from each other, corresponding to a population of people who live within the square kilometer around each point. I then want to know the relative fraction of each of those grids taken up by a circle of arbitrary size that overlaps them, so I can figure out how many people roughly live within a given circle.

Here is a practical example of one form of the problem (distances not to scale):

[image: Diagram]

I am interested in knowing the population of people who live within a radius of point X. My database figures out that its entries for points A and B are close enough to point X to be relevant. Point A in this example is something like 40.7458, -74.0375, and point B is something like 40.7458, -74.0292. Each of those green lines from A and B to its grid edge represents 0.5 km, so that the gray circle around A and B each represent 1 km^2 respectively.

Point X is at around 40.744, -74.032, and has a radius (in purple) of 0.05 km.

Now I can easily calculate the red lines shown using geographic trig functions. So I know that the line AX is about .504 km, and the distance line BX is about .309 km, for whatever that gets me.

So my question is thus: what's a solid way for calculating the fraction of grid A and the fraction of grid B taken up by the purple circle inscribed around X?

Ultimately I will be taking the population totals and multiplying them by this fraction. So in this case, the 1 km^2 grid around corresponds to 9561 people, and the grid around B is 10763 people. So if I knew (just hypothetically) that the radius around X covered 1% of the area of A and 3% of the area of B, I could make a reasonable back-of-the-envelope estimate of the total population covered by that circle by multiplying the A and B populations by their respective fractions and just summing them.

I've only done it with two squares above, but depending on the size of the radius (which can be arbitrary), there may be a whole host of possible squares, like so, making it a more general problem:

[image: Diagram 1]

In some cases, where it is easy to figure out that the square grid in question is 100% encompassed by the radius, it is in principle pretty easy (e.g. if the distance between AX was smaller than the radius around X, I know I don't have to do any further math).

Now, it's easy enough to figure out which points are within the range of the circle. But I'm a little stuck on figuring out what fractions of their corresponding areas are.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In computer graphics, when people want to draw anti-aliased stuff, they use a value called alpha to describe how much of a pixel is covered by a shape. Not all assume pixels to be simple squares, but many do. So looking for circle scan conversion algorithms which compute coverage around the border might be helpful. In any case, the separate horizontal and vertical distance to the nearest centers will likely be of more use than the straight line distance, since the former relates the point to the edge separating the areas associated with each grid point.

Comment: Thanks — that's a really interesting approach to it that I didn't think of before. Googling "circle scan conversion algorithm" comes up with a lot of promising sites. Glad to know this is a non-trivial problem and not just me being dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up coming up with what worked out to be a pretty good approximate solution, I think. Here is how it looks in PHP:

```
//$p is an array of latitude, longitude, value, and distance from the centerpoint 
//$cx,$cy are the lat/lon of the center point, $cr is the radius of the circle
//$pdist is the distance from each node to its edge (in this case, .5 km, since it is a 1km x 1km grid)

function sum_circle($p, $cx, $cy, $cr, $pdist) {
    $total = 0; //initialize the total
    $hyp = sqrt(($pdist*$pdist)+($pdist*$pdist)); //hypotenuse of distance

    for($i=0; $i<count($p); $i++) { //cycle over all points
        $px = $p[$i][0];    //x value of point
        $py = $p[$i][1];    //y value of point
        $pv = $p[$i][2];    //associated value of point (e.g. population)
        $dist = $p[$i][3];  //calculated distance of point coordinate to centerpoint

        //first, the easy case — items that are well outside the maximum distance
        if($dist>$cr+$hyp) { //if the distance is greater than circle radius plus the hypoteneuse
            $per = 0; //then use 0% of its associated value
        } else if($dist+$hyp<=$cr) { //other easy case - completely inside circle (distance + hypotenuse <= radius)
            $per = 1; //then use 100% of its associated value
        } else { //the edge cases
            $mx = ($cx-$px); $my = ($cy-$py); //calculate the angle of the difference
            $theta = abs(rad2deg(atan2($my,$mx)));
            $theta = abs((($theta + 89) % 90 + 90) % 90 - 89); //reduce it to a positive degree between 0 and 90
            $tf = abs(1-($theta/45)); //this basically makes it so that if the angle is close to 45, it returns 0, 
                                      //if it is close to 0 or 90, it returns 1
            $hyp_adjust = ($hyp*(1-$tf)+($pdist*$tf)); //now we create a mixed value that is weighted by whether the
                                                        //hypotenuse or the distance between cells should be used                                                   

            $per = ($cr-$dist+$hyp_adjust)/100; //lastly, we use the above numbers to estimate what percentage of 
                                                //the square associated with the centerpoint is covered
            if($per>1) $per = 1; //normalize for over 100% or under 0%
            if($per<0) $per = 0; 
        }
        $total+=$per*$pv;   //add the value multiplied by the percentage to the total
    }  
    return $total;
}
```

This seems to work and is pretty fast (even though it does use some trig on the edge cases). The basic logic is that when calculating edge cases, the two extreme possibilities is that the circle radius is either exactly perpendicular to the grid, or exactly at 45 degree angles from it. So it figures out roughly where between those extremes it falls and then uses that to figure out roughly what percentage of the grid square is covered. It gives plausible results in my testing.

For the size of the squares and circles I am using, this seems to be adequate?

I wrote a little application in Processing.js to try and help me work this out. Without explaining all of it, you can see how the algorithm is "thinking" by looking at this screenshot:

[image: My little example]
Basically, if the circle is yellow it means it has already figured out it is 100% in, and if it is red it is already quickly screened as 100% out. The other cases are the edge cases. The number (ranging from 0 to 1) under the dot is the (rounded) percentage of coverage calculated using the above method, while the number under that is the calculated theta value used in the above code.

For my purposes I think this approximation is workable.

Answer (score 1):

With enough classification (sketched below) all computations can be reduced to a *primitive* calculation, the one that provides the *angular area* of the orange region depicted in the image

[image]

When `y0 > 0`, as illustrated above, and regardless of whether `x0` is positive or negative, the orange area can be calculated accurately as the integral from `x0` to `x1` of `sqrt(r^2 - y^2)` minus the rectangular area `(x1 - x0) * (y1 - y0).` The integral has a well known closed expression and therefore there is no need to use any numerical algorithm for calculating it.

Other intersections between a circle and a square can be reduced to a combination of rectangles and right-angular shapes as the one painted in orange above. For instance, an intersection delimited by the horizontal and vertical orange rays in the following picture can be expressed by summing the area of the red rectangle plus two angular shapes: the blue and the green.

[image]

The blue area results from a direct application of the primitive case identified above (where the inferior rectangle collapses to nothing.) The green one can also be measured in the same way, once the negative `y` coordinate is replaced by its absolute value (the other `y` being `0`).

Applying these ideas one could enumerate all cases. Basically, one should consider the case where just one, two, three or four corners of the square lie inside the circle, while the remaining (if any) fall outside. The enumeration is a problem in itself, but it can be solved, at least in theory, by considering a relatively small number of "typical" configurations.

For each of the cases enumerated as described a decomposition on some few rectangles and angular areas has to be calculated and the parts added up (or subtracted) as shown in the three-color example above. The area of every part would reduce to rectangular or primitive angular areas.

A considerably amount of work has to be done to turn this line of attack into a working algorithm. A deeper analysis could shed some light on how to minimize the number of "typical" configurations to consider. If not, I think that the amount of combinations to consider, however large, should be manageable.

Answer (score 0):

In case your problem admits an approximate answer there is another technique you could use which is much simpler to program. The whole idea of this problem reduces to calculate the area of the intersection of a square and a circle. I didn't explain this in my other answer, but finding the squares that are likely to intercept the circle shouldn't be a problem, otherwise, let us know.

The idea of calculating the approximate area of the intersection is very simple. Generate enough points in the square at random and check how many of them belong in the circle. The ratio between the number of points in the circle and the total number of random points in the square will give you the proportion of the intersection with respect to the square's area.

Now, given that you have to repeat the same routine for all squares surrounding the circle (i.e., squares which center has a distance to the circle's center not very different from the circle's radius) you could re-use the random points by translating them from one square to the other.

I don't want to go into details if this method is not appropriate for your problem, so let me just indicate that generating random points uniformly distributed in the square is fairly easy. You only need to generate random numbers for the `x` coordinate and, independently, random numbers for `y`. Then just consider all pairs `(x, y)`. Then, for every `(x, y)` verify whether `(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 <= r^2` or not, where `(a, b)` stands for the circle's center and `r` for the radius.